# Event Hooks for Google Photos API

Tags: c#, google-photos, google-photos-api

I am wondering whether the Google Photos API offers an interface for events/hooks. Ideally, I would like to provide a callback URL/endpoint can is hit every time a new album etc. is created. Reading the docs I cannot determine whether this is possible?

Comment: Looking at the docs, I think you're right that it's not a supported scenario - I think it would be pretty obvious if it had something like this.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think you're right. I thought I would ask just-in-case as Google isn't exactly known for it easy to understand/follow documentation... Thanks though!